# Setting ESP Preferences from commandline using tshark

Tags: wireshark

There is a scripting need where i have to set the ESP preferences using tshark commandline. Does any one have idea how to pass this preferences from tshark commandline Ex: below

tshark -R "sip" -2 -r 131104_pcap.pcap -o esp.enable_null_encryption_decode_heuristic:true

I tried using the above command but getting the error "unknown preference" (May be because -o specifies change in preferences rather than esap_sa) I am using wireshark 1.8 on my pc. I see a file esp_sa in \Appdata\wireshark\ with below line "IPv4","","","*","AES-CBC [RFC3602]","0x3732297C3619A67029FA2C045869EDE1","HMAC-MD5-96 [RFC2403]","0x2B9F652AC3C0E6AEF19B82B060F28E6A" after adding the same from GUI. Also i see preferences file in the same location

So Is there any way to change this esp_qa using tshark line ??

Answer (score 0):

The above command (with, of course, a different SIP capture file) works with my 1.8 version of tshark (i.e. no "unknown preference" message).

So: is this a "regions and languages" localization issue ?

Are you able to specify *any* preference ? For example:

```
tshark -o tcp.summary_in_tree:false
```